# How can i get the value of a dropdown after it is selected

Tags: angular

Below specified is my data

```
Id , Name  , IsBillable
1    One       1
2    two       0
3.   three     0
```

this will be the dropdown value below i'll share the html dropdown code

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of masterAppointmentTypes" [value]="option.id">
                    {{option.value}}
 </mat-option>
```

the above html works. All i need to do is: get the IsBillable data at the below code

```
if(this.appointmentForm.get('id').value == this.appointmentForm.get('id').value && this.appointmentForm.get('IsBillable').value){
      this.openPaymentDialog(appointmentData, queryParams)
    }
    else{
      this.createAppointment(appointmentData, queryParams);
    }
```

at the above code i get the ID value according to the selected dropdown but i didn't get IsBillable data according to the selected id.Below code is my formBuilder.

```
const configControls = {
    
      'AppointmentTypeID': [appointmentObj.appointmentTypeID, Validators.required],
      'IsBillable' : [appointmentObj.isBillable,Validators.required],
    
      
    }
    this.appointmentForm = this.formBuilder.group(configControls);
```

Comment: are you using angular material `mat-select`? If so there is `selectionChange` https://material.angular.io/components/select/api. `(selectionChange)="callSomeFunction($event)"`

Answer (score 0):

You don`t need the two formControls. you can do the following:

```
const configControls = {

  'AppointmentType': [appointmentObj, Validators.required],

}
this.appointmentForm = this.formBuilder.group(configControls);
```

then:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of masterAppointmentTypes" [value]="option">
                    {{option.value}}
 </mat-option>
```

you should have what you want at:

```
this.appointmentForm.get('AppointmentType').value.IsBillable
```

The thing is, you were using a formControl to get the Id on the select, and it was doing that correctly, what it does not do is sync with the other form control to match the isBillable on select, that's just an initial value for the control, not a reference to be updated. That's why you have to get() the form control from the group and then access it's value to get what you want.

you can read more at: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: how can i get the isbillable data only like i get ID data

Comment: the isBillable data is in your second formControl, i presume that form control must be bound to another input element, so in your code you would get that by this.appointmentForm.get('IsBillable').value. Assuming everything is wired up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky, please check the demo example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-kyjxuu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Html Part:

```
 <div style="padding: 20px">
  <h3>Value variable</h3>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select #valueCountry>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let data of datas" [value]="data">
        {{ data.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div>
  Selected Id : {{ selectedData?.id }} <br />
  Selected Name : {{ selectedData?.name }} <br />Selected isBillable :
  {{ selectedData?.isBillable }}
</div>
```

Component Part:

```
@ViewChild('valueCountry') valueCountry: MatSelect;

  selectedData;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.valueCountry.selectionChange.subscribe(this.onChange.bind(this));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.valueCountry.selectionChange.unsubscribe();
  }

  datas: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'One',
      isBillable: true,
    },

    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Two',
      isBillable: false,
    },

    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Three',
      isBillable: false,
    },
  ];

  onChange(event) {
    this.selectedData = event.value;
  }
```

Comment: remember to unsubscribe from dom event listeners using ngOnDestroy or you leave the subscription dangling causing a memory leak. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription

Comment: i got this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selectionChange')

Comment: error is from in this line of code this.valueChanged.selectionChange.subscribe(this.onChange.bind(this));

Comment: i think you forget to add the @ViewChild('valueCountry') valueCountry: MatSelect; with type and please also confirm the angular material version